# Two fields (out of 18) in a PDF form don't appear after filling and flattening with iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm using the latest version of iText (5.5.0) to fill a pdf form and flatten it.

For some reason when I fill the form using an fdf everything works except for special chars like 'ç'. But when I use an xfdf the special chars appear but two fields do not ('comment' and 'datelicFormatted')

-> see https://upl.cases.lu/?action=d&id=82085749396826225834 for the template, the xpdf and a result

The form was created by converting a word document and adding text fields with acrobat 10.

The really strange part is when I ask not to flatten it: the fields contain the right values, they just seem to vanish when flattened.

Thank you for any help you could provide.

Comment: By the way. By testing the solutions on this page: http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Form-Flattening-td3818310.html I noticed that the com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields.regenerateField method has a problem: If the value of a field is too long or has a newline (not sure what exactly), it fails because the display argument is set as the value.

Comment: I have examined the form and the first thing that caught my eyes, is that the two missing fields are the only fields that are defined using ArialUnicodeMS, whereas the other fields use Helvetica. I'm not sure yet, as to what goes wrong, though.

Comment: I have found the exact place where the text of the two missing fields changes into an empty String. The font is indeed the culprit. Now I have to find out what is going wrong exactly.

Comment: I've written a hack that solves the problem; this hack may or may not be added to the next release. I've created a ticket on the paid support system at iText Software for the core developers to take a look at the hack (and to accept or refuse it). What is the essence of the problem: iText looks at the fonts in the document, finds ArialUnicodeMS for the two problematic fields, then searches the font for the characters needed, doesn't find them in the font (maybe because of the form, this remains to be tested) and unfound characters disappear.

Comment: Not sure that is the reason. Apparently it's an adobe acrobat 10 problem: I found a workaround. When creating the form acrobat automatically creates textfields where it thinks there should be some -> acrobat seems to create them with an appearance and they work after flattening. When you create by hand new text fields you end up with the problem I had. iText seems to flatten correctly and leaves out the fields without appearance (those fields don't ven get printed). I have to contact adobe about this. For special characters to appear there have to define the font as Arial Unicode MS

Comment: I have some contacts at Adobe. If you don't get an answer, let me know and I'll use a short-cut to the engineers who wrote the Acrobat code.

Answer (score 0):

Your template indeed uses the font Arial Unicode MS that could be interpreted by iText correctly only with some extra resource(CMAP UniKS-UTF16-H). The ordinary iText JARS does not contain such resources by design. But there is one more iText JAR - itext-asia.jar that contains CMAPs  resources. So just added itext-asia.jar to your classpath and the problematic fields will be flattened correctly. Your could download itext-asia.jar at http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/files/extrajars/extrajars-2.3.zip/download